# Dataframe empty when passing column names

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am facing issue where on passing numpy array to dataframe without column names initializes it properly. Whereas, if I pass column names, it is empty.

```
x = np.array([(1, '1'), (2, '2')], dtype = 'i4,S1')
df = pd.DataFrame(x)
In []: df
Out[]: 
   f0 f1
0   1  1
1   2  2

df2 = pd.DataFrame(x, columns=['a', 'b'])
In []: df2
Out[]: 
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [a, b]
Index: []
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need specify column names in parameter `dtype`, see [DataFrame from structured or record array](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#from-structured-or-record-array):

```
x = np.array([(1, '1'), (2, '2')], dtype=[('a', 'i4'),('b', 'S1')])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(x)
print (df2)
   a     b
0  1  b'1'
1  2  b'2'
```

Another solution without parameter `dtype`:

```
x = np.array([(1, '1'), (2, '2')])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(x, columns=['a', 'b'])
print (df2)
   a  b
0  1  1
1  2  2
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the `dtype` param, without specifiying it, it works as expected.
See the example at documentation [DataFrame](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

x = np.array([(1, "11"), (2, "22")])
df = pd.DataFrame(x)
print df

df2 = pd.DataFrame(x, columns=['a', 'b'])
print df2
```